# AST (abstract syntax tree) view in Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans-7, abstract-syntax-tree, netbeans-plugins

Eclipse offers a plugin, which displays the abstract tree view of Java projects. After installing the plugin, the view becomes available. http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php

Is there such a functionality / plugin also available for the Netbeans IDE? I didn't find an answer in stackoverflow. The results in Google dealing with AST in Netbeans are somewhat old (2007-2009).

I know that there are standalone tools which display the AST and also other IDEs which are more useful, if such functionality is required (like IntelliJ Idea).

My question is Netbeans-specific - if this is not possible with Netbeans (without using other tools) a simple "No" will be enough! I am using Netbeans 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at these ? It is more recent (2012).

http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-javac-ast-visualization

https://bitbucket.org/crazyjavahacking

Answer (score 0):

The dev builds of NB already contain such a view in the navigator. Not pretty but it works
[image]